# Remember If Music Player is Playing

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

So I have an HTML5 audio player which plays a radio stream, but upon page refresh or new page it will stop playing and have to be manually started again,

I was wondering how i would get it to remember if a user had clicked play ?

A lil Google and i found out that it's to do with cookies however i know nothing about cookies so any help will be great thanks!

Comment: sorry to cause conflict guys, i was asking how and that Google told me it was something to do with Cookies i never asked specifically for a cookie based solution

Comment: @Paul: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage#Client-side_interface

Comment: @PaulSmith Thanks for the clarification, and sorry for the inappropriate argument. I suggest you edit your question to clarify that you're not looking for a solution that necessarily uses cookies.

Answer (score 1):

With your clarification in comments that you're not specifically looking for a cookie-based solution, the best solution to this would be to use localStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

One way you could do this:

```
// When the music player starts
window.localStorage.setItem("isPlaying", true);

// When the music player stops
window.localStorage.removeItem("isPlaying");

// When the page loads
if (window.localStorage.getItem("isPlaying") {
    // Trigger the music player to start
}
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I apologize for our previous conversation.

Comment: Wasn't really much of a conversation, eh? ;) Back at ya.